# ant javac exclude everything not included

Tags: java, ant, build, javac

I am trying to write a build script for a REST service which sits on top of our existing business logic layer, however, I only want to include the minimal amount of sources to keep the service small and only contain what it absolutely needs.

Below is my current compile target. I am able to either include everything or nothing. I assume I am making a simple mistake I can't seem to spot or find online.

```
<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${build.classes.dir}"/>
    <javac source="1.6"
           target="1.6"
           encoding="UTF-8"
           debug="true"
           debuglevel="lines,vars,source"
           srcdir="${basedir}"
           destdir="${build.classes.dir}"
           includeAntRuntime="false">
        <src>
            <dirset dir="${src.eai.dir}" errorOnMissingDir="true">
                <include name="common/vo/MyPojo.java"/>
                <include name="common/SomeException.java"/>
            </dirset>
            <dirset dir="${src.ets.dir}" errorOnMissingDir="true">
                <include name="common/vo/AnotherPojo.java" />
                <include name="price/vo/YetAnotherPojo.java" />
                <include name="price/vo/OneMorePojo.java" />
            </dirset>
            <dirset dir="${src.java.dir}" errorOnMissingDir="true">
                <include name="java"/>
            </dirset>
        </src>
        <!-- this line ignores everything, without it it includes everything -->
        <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
        <classpath refid="classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>
```

Is there a way to only include the files specified above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In place of `exclude`, try `include` and list your java files separated with comma(,) e.g:

```
<include name="common/vo/MyPojo.java,common/SomeException.java,common/vo/AnotherPojo.java,price/vo/YetAnotherPojo.java" />
```

Comment: This is not ideal, but it works. thanks. The other thing I had to do was ad the `**/` in front of everything.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set both the `srcdir` attribute and the nested `<src>` element, as I imagine Ant is simply combining the two.